# angular ui-grid How to raise afterCellEdit event explicitly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am working on Angular UI-Grid and binding the data from SharePoint List. Everything is dynamic in this app including column definition and data. Also, I am integrating Sharepoint controls as edit templates.

So, can anyone tell me how to raise aftercelledit event for a custom editable template. I found syntax for the same but getting undefined for argument passed in this:

```
$scope.grid.api.edit.raise.afterCellEdit($scope.row.entity, $scope.col.colDef, cellModel($scope), origCellValue);
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks,

Comment: The syntax you wrote is right, you should build a plunkr showing the issue in your code for other people to help you.